# UIScrollView content to track a CAKeyFrameAnimation along a path

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, caanimation

In my App I have a full-screen UIScrollView where the content is a UIImageView containing a map image which is about 2000px square (i.e. larger than the UIScrollView).

Currently, I plot a path across the map and animate a "beacon" image along it using a CAKeyFrameAnimation, which works great.

What I would like to be able to do is to make the UIScrollView content move with the animation in such a way as to keep the beacon image in the centre of the screen (giving the user the impression of tracking along the path).

Any suggestions on how I might achieve this?